# MySQL Compare VARCHAR Columns

Tags: mysql, casting, varchar

I have a column named `D1_VAL`

The rows in this column have data that looks like this:

```
C:10
R:200
E:3
N:77
```

I'm trying to do a search on these values with a logical operator. I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM d1 WHERE CAST(`D1_VAL` AS UNSIGNED) > 5
```

It doesn't return any rows. I've also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM d1 WHERE (0 + `D1_VAL`) > 5
```

How would I do this properly?

Comment: Is it always a one char plus colon in the begin of each string or it can vary?

Comment: @zerkms It's always one char + colon

Comment: You will get much more efficient searching if you break it into two columns and then treat the second column as a proper integral typed column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query will do,

```
SELECT * FROM d1 WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(`D1_VAL`, 3) AS UNSIGNED) > 5
```

But its better to normalize the values like `C:10` to two separate columns.

```
create table d1(
    letter char(1),
    number int,
    // ... other columns
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the comparison you are trying to do?

If compare the number (on the righ to colon) against 5, try something like this:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(`D1_VAL`, INSTR(`D1_VAL`, `:`)) AS UNSIGNED) > 5
```

For more information on string functions, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html).

Also, I would suggest having a think about the database design - i.e. would the contents of this column be better off being stored in two columns - e.g. a char and an integer? That would be more efficient - requiring less disk space and allowing faster queries. If you have lots of rows, doing various string functions, casting etc. could make your queries run quite slowly.